# how to slice queryList and show the new array(new QueryList) in angular

Tags: angular

in my avatar-list.html:

```html
<ng-template>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

and in avatar-list.component.ts:

```
 @ContentChildren(ThyAvatarComponent)
    private set avatarComponents(value: QueryList<ThyAvatarComponent>) {
        this.avatarItems = value.toArray();
        this.avatarList = value;
    }
```

I use avatar-list like this:

```html
<thy-avatar-list>
  <thy-avatar-component *showDetailTip ></thy-avatar-component>
  <thy-avatar-component *showDetailTip ></thy-avatar-component>
</thy-avatar-list>
```

I add some directive for thyAvatarComponent.
Now,I want to slice this.avatarList,show part of this.avatarList in html, how should I do?

I try to use slicePipe in avatar-list.html:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of avatarItems | slice : 0 : showCount">
  <!--? -->
</div>
```

but I don't know how to show the itme(avatarComponent with directive) in line 2?

Answer (score 1):

To access the individual items of avatarItems in your HTML template, you can use the ngFor directive and iterate over avatarItems directly.

**Here's an example:**

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of avatarItems.slice(0, showCount)">
  <!-- Display item properties or use them within the <ng-content> -->
  <p>{{ item.someProperty }}</p>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

**slice** method is called directly on avatarItems within the ngFor directive, allowing you to display only the desired number of items based on the showCount variable.

Make sure to replace someProperty with the actual property name you want to display from item. You can access any property of item inside the  as needed.

Also, ensure that the  is being used correctly as the parent container for the content projection () in the consuming component

`**Updated Answer**`

In your avatar-list.component.ts file, add a public property to hold the sliced avatarItems:

```
public slicedAvatarItems: ThyAvatarComponent[];
@ContentChildren(ThyAvatarComponent)
private set avatarComponents(value: QueryList<ThyAvatarComponent>) {
  this.avatarItems = value.toArray();
  this.avatarList = value;
  this.slicedAvatarItems = this.avatarItems.slice(0, this.showCount);
}
```

**html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of slicedAvatarItems">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.templateRef"></ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

`**get templateRef in ThyAvatarComponent**`

**Ts**

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ContentChildren(ThyAvatarComponent)
@ViewChild(ThyAvatarComponent, { read: TemplateRef }) avatarComponents: QueryList<ThyAvatarComponent>;
```

**HTML**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of avatarComponents">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.templateRef"></ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

`**Updated answer**`

avatar-list.component.html:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

avatar-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList, AfterContentInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ThyAvatarComponent } from './thy-avatar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'thy-avatar-list',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of templateRefs">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="item"></ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  `,
})
export class ThyAvatarListComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(ThyAvatarComponent, { read: ElementRef }) avatarComponents: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  templateRefs: Array<ElementRef<HTMLElement>> = [];

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.avatarComponents.forEach((avatarComponent) => {
      this.templateRefs.push(avatarComponent.nativeElement);
    });
  }
}
```

thy-avatar.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'thy-avatar-component',
  template: `
    <ng-template #avatarTemplate>
      <!-- Your avatar component template here -->
      <div>{{ avatarData }}</div>
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class ThyAvatarComponent {
  avatarData = 'Avatar Data';
}
```

Comment: sorry,my bad,I didn't make it clear
if I add some directive for component,this way can't do it:
 use like this:
```html
<avatar-list>
<thy-avatar-component *showDetailTip></thy-avatar-component>
<thy-avatar-component *showDetailTip></thy-avatar-component>
</avatar-list>
```
and use your way can't add showDetailTip directive for new array

Comment: @SanOld you want to add the showDetailTip directive dynamically to the ThyAvatarComponent instances within the avatarList array?

Comment: @SanOld i updated my answer please check hope its's helps..

Comment: thanks a lot. but I don't know how get `item.templateRef` value,in this case ,item is ThyAvatarComponent,how do I get templateRef in ThyAvatarComponent.
I tried several methods, but none of them worked.

Comment: @SanOld again i update my answer please check i think it helps

Comment: Thank you very much again. But It isn't work on my case.
And I don't understand 
`@ContentChildren(ThyAvatarComponent)
@ViewChild(ThyAvatarComponent, { read: TemplateRef }) avatarComponents: QueryList<ThyAvatarComponent>;` this code ,I wrote it in my avatar-list.component.ts, i get twice data,one is queryList (there is not templateRef in first object value),two is undefined.

Comment: @SanOld please check bottom i updated the answer